# Are using arrays or 1 row dataFrames faster?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am creating a row of data 1 column at a time which I store in a 1 row dataframe and then append it to a larger dataframe. I don't know if I should be using an array to store the row of data and then append it onto the larger dataframe or just stay consistent with only dataframes. I am mainly wondering what is fastest or if it matters all that much. I'm pretty new to pandas so let me know if you need more information. The row of data contains 15 columns and I'm appending it onto a 3000+ row dataframe.

The one thing that makes me think it might be slower using a dataframe is that I'm creating a 15 new columns when creating the single row dataframe.

```
for i in range(5):
    df[str(lower) + ' Column1'] = some_number
    df[str(lower) + ' Column2'] = some_number
    df[str(lower) + ' Column3'] = some_number
```

Comment: if you are growing things one at a time, neither an array nor a dataframe will be performant. Probably, you should use a `list` then convert to either an array or a dataframe

Comment: Are all the columns of the same types? If not what are the column types? Do you know the number of row to append before appending them? Note that `str(lower)` is quite slow and could be put outside the loop and the concatenated string too here.

Comment: No not all the columns are the same type. 1st is a date, 2nd and third are strings and the rest are decimals. str(lower) changes after each time through the loop (lower increases by 50).